# How to learn image processing in an applicational way?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, self-study

My question is for image processing and computer vision "practitioner" who study on a company. Since I have an degree on electrical engineering and mathematics, I have signal processing, probability, calculus, linear algebra and programming background. Now I am learning image processing and computer vision. Since I am not in academia and work in a company that focuses on the project and works result-oriented, the implementation of algorithms becomes more important.However, like my other colleagues, I cannot work by copying "ready codes" and just playing with the parameters. It is very important that I should understand the mathematics and logic. I should take hand written notes. But my software engineer teammates just use computer for searching the solution and they are just trying to get the result without understanding exactly what they are doing. The sad part is that it works! Is is really what should we do?When I make time for understanding the theory, ideas etc, I miss deadlines because they are waiting for results. As if all the known theoretical backgrounds were unnecessary. Do you provide the balance between theory and practice, especially for these fields whose application is more common?

Comment: Copy-pasting code from the internet into production code is bad. Doing that without understanding it is way worse. I shudder at the thought of having to maintain that code. :(

Comment: "Copy-pasting code from the internet" This is not the main issue I'm complaining about. Please read more carefully. @Cris Luengo

Comment: I read carefully enough. I’m commenting on what your colleagues do. I feel sorry for you, having to work with them. I’m glad I’m not working with them. I’m not going to comment on the rest of your post because I’m not your manager.

Answer (score -2):

1. Read the book [Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications](http://szeliski.org/Book/).
2. Solve the exercises in Python / Matlab.